# Setting which domain a G Suite account is added to api

Tags: php, api, google-workspace

I've got my website hooked up to G Suite so I can enter new user details on the site and the user is created on G suite. This all works fine. My issue is now I have two domains configured and I want to be able to add users to the new one which is not primary.
At the moment I've got the following which pushes the new users into the primary domain.

```
$suggestedEmail = strtolower(str_replace(" ", ".",strtr($fullNameEmail, $normalizeChars))).'@domain.com';

$userInstance->setPrimaryEmail($suggestedEmail);
```

What I've tried is simply changing the code to this:

```
$suggestedEmail = strtolower(str_replace(" ", ".",strtr($fullNameEmail, $normalizeChars))).'@sub.domain.com';
```

But the new user is still being create in the primary domain.
Any clues?